# C#: Out of memory Exception

Tags: c#

I have written a console application

```
   Int64 sum = 0;
        int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Int64[] input = new Int64[T];
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
        {
            input[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
        {
            int[,] Matrix = new int[input[i], input[i]];
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < input[i]; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < input[i]; k++)
                {

                    Matrix[j, k] = Math.Abs(j - k);
                    sum += Matrix[j, k];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
```

When I gave input as

```
2
1
999999
```

It gave  `Out of memory exception`. Can you please help.

Comment: You are trying to allocate space that is not available, as arrays need consecutive memory location, you will get exception even you can see required space is available because that may not be consecutive.

Comment: You're trying to allocate an array of size 3.7TB. My guess is that you don't have that much memory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you are allocating:

`input[]` is allocated as 2 elements (16 bytes) - no worries

But then you enter values: `1` and `999999` and in the first iteration of the loop attempt to allocate

Matrix[1,1]  = 4 bytes - again no worries,

but the second time round you try to allocate

Matrix[999999, 999999]

which is 4 * 10e12 bytes and certainly beyond the capacity of your computer even with swap space on the disk.

I suspect that this is not what you really want to allocate (you'd never be able to fill or manipulate that many elements anyway...)

If you are merely trying to do the calculations as per your original code, there is not need to allocate or use the array, as you only ever store one value and immediately use that value and then never again.

```
Int64 sum = 0;
int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Int64[] input = new Int64[T];

for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    input[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    // int[,] Matrix = new int[input[i], input[i]];
    sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < input[i]; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < input[i]; k++)
            {
                //Matrix[j, k] = Math.Abs(j - k);
                //sum += Matrix[j, k];
                sum += Math.Abs(j - k);
            }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

But now beware - a trillion sums is going to take forever to calculate - it won't bomb out, but you might like to take a vacation, get married and have kids before you can expect a result.

Comment: I have to send this input as per requirement. Is changing the dataType will help?

Comment: @AnkurGupta - what are your actual requirements? what is it you are really trying to do, and put that in your question.

Comment: @AnkurGupta - changing the data type will make little difference. It will change it from 4 trillion (int) to 2 trillion (char) or 1 trillion (byte)  - all still the same order of magnitude. as user1666620 asks - what are you really trying to do here. There is very little programming you can do with this order of magnitude of data.

Comment: @ubercoder I am trying to make a 2d array and store the values and sum up there values. I can do it directly but I am trying to do via array if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course instead of doing the full squared set of calculations, you can calculate the sum thus:

```
for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    sum = 0;

    for (int j = 1, term = 0; j < input[i]; j++)
    {
        term += j;
        sum += term * 2;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

So now the calculation is O(n) instead of O(n^2)

And if you need to know what the value in `Matrix[x,y]` would have been, you can calculate it by the simple expression `Math.Abs(x - y)` thus there is no need to store that value.